# How to send unique range of cells to listed email?

Tags: list, email, google-apps-script

I am a school teacher working on a document for my school to be able to request students by teacher but I'm having a lot of trouble getting the code set up to send the email to their A2/B6 teacher.  The part of the process I need help with is layers into the project, so the data compiled is very complex and I've read a lot of helps from stackoverflow over the last 2 weeks but I can't find anything that shows me or that even gets me started on this specific task.

I have a row that contains emails of teachers.  Below their email is a column of their students' names and next to that is another row that contains data (the requesting teacher's name).  I need to write a script that will take the email in cell "A2" and send it the range of data in "A3:B20," take the email in cell "C2" and send it the range of data in "C3:D20," take the email in cell "E2" and send it the range of data in "E3:F20," and so on and so forth for 75+ teachers.

[Here is a picture of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1D8l.png)

Really what my question is, ***IS THIS POSSIBLE***?  And if so do you have any ideas that could point me in the right direction, or do you have a snippet of code you could share with me to get me started.  I am new to google scripts for this project but I've learned a lot.

Any help, insights, or suggestions would be really appreciated.

I have created a dummy document with computer-generated names here that shows what my sheet set up in like:
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QONEAxMQLBDKwgaXc4RwH_rgb_RzlxTkHl5euSSB9Wk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can gather all elements of A3:B20 in a 2D array and then create a html body string with a for loop to get data of the array in this kind of table format only and send it in the mail to the respective email

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this short example will help you to get started.

```
function myFunction() {
  var hl='';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var subject='Enter Subject Here';
  for(var col=1;col<sh.getLastColumn();col+=2){
    var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),2);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var s='StudentName,RequestingTeacher\n';
    var html='<table>';
    html+='<tr><th>StudentName</th><th>RequestingTeacher</th></tr>';
    for(var i=2;i<vA.length;i++){
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>', vA[i][0],vA[i][1]);
      s+=Utilities.formatString('%s,%s', vA[i][0],vA[i][1]);
    }
    html+='</table>';
    //GmailApp.sendEmail(vA[0][0], subject, s, {htmlBody:html});  
    hl+=Utilities.formatString('RecipientName: %s<br />RecipientEmail:%s<br />Column: %s<br />' , vA[0][0],vA[1][0],col);
    hl+=html;
    hl+='<br /><br /><br />';
  }
    var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(hl);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'An Example of What Emails Body will look like.')  

}
```

The  sendEmail line is commented out and I use a dialog to show you what the emails will look like more or less.

This is what my dialog looks like:

```
RecipientName: Test Teacher
RecipientEmail:tteacher@schooldistrict.org
Column: 1
StudentName RequestingTeacher
Braydon Nichols 
Kiley Lozano    
Shania Olsen    
Rodney Howell   Duckworth
Tiana Shelton   HOPE Squad
Stephen Wiggins Moore
Kael Rangel 
Beau Pennington 
Hezekiah Vincent    Batman
Iyana Lewis Moore
Theodore Klein  
Rubi Webster    S. Ward
Natalee Wong    Batman
Chris Rocha Batman
Eileen Smith    
Kara Johnston   
Carsen Waters   Moore
Bria Schmitt    Cotterell
Abby Yoder  
Natalie Durham  



RecipientName: Example Teacher
RecipientEmail:eteacher@schooldistrict.org
Column: 3
StudentName RequestingTeacher
Brandon Bean    
Wade Cross  
Jaxon Ford  
Josie Barajas   W. Smith
Aimee Ross  
Maren Cox   Batman
Kyle Morton 
Beatrice Hill   W. Smith
Stephen Carroll Batman
Anton Galvan    
Marlie Neal Anderson
Alexander Andersen  W. Smith
Jacquelyn Boyer 
Nora Brennan    
Derek Ayers 
Van Obrien  
Amari Rasmussen 
Aiyana Collier  Cotterell
Annalise Vance  
Kieran Booker   



RecipientName: Awesome Teacher
RecipientEmail:ateacher@schooldistrict.org
Column: 5
StudentName RequestingTeacher
Brooklynn Hahn  W. Smith
Jenny Lutz  W. Smith
Lilian Moreno   HOPE Squad
Journey Travis  
Kenna Lawson    Anderson
Kathy Mccarthy  
Dayanara Strickland Moore
Anna Knight 
Kamron Osborne  
Turner Mcintosh Cotterell
Tyrone Mullins  
Selena Oneal    
Tabitha Hernandez   
Andreas Chan    Batman
Dashawn Munoz   HOPE Squad
Laylah Morse    HOPE Squad
Jamie Anthony   
Damion Duffy    
Christina Donovan   
Hugh Gomez  



RecipientName: Dummy Teacher
RecipientEmail:dteacher@schooldistrict.org
Column: 7
StudentName RequestingTeacher
Payton Huerta   Moore
Easton Pittman  
Lyric Morrow    HOPE Squad
Jada Richardson Batman
Jon Mckay   HOPE Squad
Demetrius Horton    Anderson
Lilly Atkinson  
Spencer Mathews W. Smith
Jalen Hanna Dibb
Miracle Best    
Emerson Frost   
Colt Andersen   Dibb
Leanna Gibbs    
Liana Branch    S. Ward
Jamie Mooney    
Mara Escobar    Dibb
Liliana Galloway    Anderson
Jane Schmitt    Cotterell
Aryan Melendez  
Dalton Ritter
```